# Simple bandpass filter in java

Tags: java, matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to write a simple band pass filter following the instructions in [this book](http://www.dspguide.com/). My code creates a blackman window, and combines two low pass filter kernels to create a band pass filter kernel using spectral inversion, as described in the second example [here](http://www.dspguide.com/ch16/4.htm) (table 16-2).

I am testing my code by comparing it with the results I get in matlab. When I test the methods that create a blackman window and a low pass filter kernel separately, I get results that are close to what I see in matlab (up to some digits after the decimal point - I attribute the error to java double variables rounding issues), but my band pass filter kernel is incorrect.

Tests I ran:

- Created a blackman window and compared it with what I get in matlab - all good.
- Created a low pass filter using this window using my code and `fir1(N, Fc1/(Fs/2), win, flag);` in matlab (see full code below). I think the results are correct, although I get bigger error the bigger Fc1 is (**why?**)
- Created a pand pass filter using my code and `fir1(N, [Fc1 Fc2]/(Fs/2), 'bandpass', win, flag);` in matlab - results are completely off.
- Filtered my data using my code and the kernel generated by matlab - all good.

So - why is my band pass filter kernel off? What did I do wrong?
I think I either have a bug or fir1 uses a different algorithm, but I can't check because the [article referenced in its documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir1.html#bqih_e6-1) is not publicly available.

This is my matlab code:

```
Fs = 200;       % Sampling Frequency
N    = 10;          % Order
Fc1  = 1.5;         % First Cutoff Frequency
Fc2  = 7.5;         % Second Cutoff Frequency
flag = 'scale';     % Sampling Flag

% Create the window vector for the design algorithm.
win = blackman(N+1);

% Calculate the coefficients using the FIR1 function.
b  = fir1(N, [Fc1 Fc2]/(Fs/2), 'bandpass', win, flag);
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);
res = filter(Hd, data);
```

This is my java code (I believe the bug is in bandPassKernel):

```
/**
     * See - http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/blackman.html
     * @param length
     * @return
     */
    private static double[] blackmanWindow(int length) {

        double[] window = new double[length];
        double factor = Math.PI / (length - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < window.length; ++i) {
            window[i] = 0.42d - (0.5d * Math.cos(2 * factor * i)) + (0.08d * Math.cos(4 * factor * i));
        }

        return window;
    }

private static double[] lowPassKernel(int length, double cutoffFreq, double[] window) {

    double[] ker = new double[length + 1];
    double factor = Math.PI * cutoffFreq * 2; 
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ker.length; i++) {
        double d = i - length/2; 
        if (d == 0) ker[i] = factor;
        else ker[i] =  Math.sin(factor * d) / d;
        ker[i] *= window[i];
        sum += ker[i];
    }

    // Normalize the kernel
    for (int i = 0; i < ker.length; ++i) {
        ker[i] /= sum;
    }

    return ker;
}

private static double[] bandPassKernel(int length, double lowFreq, double highFreq) {

    double[] ker = new double[length + 1];
    double[] window = blackmanWindow(length + 1);

    // Create a band reject filter kernel using a high pass and a low pass filter kernel 
    double[] lowPass = lowPassKernel(length, lowFreq, window);

    // Create a high pass kernel for the high frequency
    // by inverting a low pass kernel
    double[] highPass = lowPassKernel(length, highFreq, window);
    for (int i = 0; i < highPass.length; ++i) highPass[i] = -highPass[i];
    highPass[length / 2] += 1;

    // Combine the filters and invert to create a bandpass filter kernel
    for (int i = 0; i < ker.length; ++i) ker[i] = -(lowPass[i] + highPass[i]);
    ker[length / 2] += 1;

    return ker;
}

private static double[] filter(double[] signal, double[] kernel) {

    double[] res = new double[signal.length];

    for (int r = 0; r < res.length; ++r) {

        int M = Math.min(kernel.length, r + 1);
        for (int k = 0; k < M; ++k) {
            res[r] += kernel[k] * signal[r - k];
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

And this is how I use my code:

```
double[] kernel = bandPassKernel(10, 1.5d / (200/2), 7.5d / (200/2));
double[] res = filter(data, kernel);
```

Comment: There is an implementation of [`fir1` in Octave-Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/function/fir1.html) - perhaps you could check your algorithm against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing Matlab's fir1 function in Java. My results are quite accurate.

Comment: For anyone who might search for the fir1 function it's availble for reading here:  https://github.com/vojd/octave-signal-1.3.2/blob/master/inst/fir1.m  Please note that the real repo for Octave and its Signal package is on SourceForge.